# Prevent the same setFlash() message from being output on every page

Tags: session, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am new to CakePHP and have inherited a project which uses CakePHP v1.3 and displays various messages to the user using `$this->Session->setFlash()`.

One such instance where the message is displaying is after a successful login to the site. The problem is, the same message will pop up on every subsequent page that the user visits. How do I prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show flashMessages only *once*, you should output them using;

```
echo $this->Session->flash();
```

Inside your view. See [Displaying notifications or flash messages](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Helpers/Session.html#flash)

This method will remove the output from the session after displaying it.

If you're displaying those messages via some custom method, be sure to clear the message from the session afterward, using;

```
$this->Session->delete('Message.flash');
```

Inside your view

Comment: Great! Thanks. I was hoping to be able to call that method inside afterRender() or afterFilter() but no such luck.